# How to query a date with Semantic Mediawiki 1.9

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I am using Semantic Mediawiki 1.9 and I have no idea why this query is not working:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Group]][[EndDate::>{{#time:d F Y }}]] |?HasResponsible=|link=none|mainlabel=-}}
```

PS: when I replace `{{CURRENTDAY}} {{CURRENTMONTHNAME}} {{CURRENTYEAR}}` Or`{{#time:d F Y }}` by 21 March 2014 ,it works!!!

Comment: Have you asked on the Semantic Mediawiki mailing list? See http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki_mailing_lists for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a standard time format. `{{#time:Y-m-d}}` should work:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Group]][[EndDate::>{{#time:Y-m-d}}]]
|?HasResponsible=
|link=none
|mainlabel=-}}
```

`{{#time:d F Y}}` will give different strings depending on your language settings, and SMW only understand month names in English.